# Is there a way to force WhatsApp to work on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: whatsapp, 7.x, nokia-lumia-610

On December 31, [WhatsApp ended support for Windows Phone 7](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/wp/21478428).

Is there a way to force the app to continue working anyway?

I'm on a Nokia Lumia 610 if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WhatsApp will not work anymore on Windows Phone 7 devices. I can confirm this because it no longer works on my WP7 device.

Answer (score 4):

> This means that if you are currently using WhatsApp on a Windows Phone 7, you will **be able to continue to use** WhatsApp on that phone during this period.
>
> However, as part of this process, after July 1st, 2016 it **will not be possible to create** a WhatsApp account on a Windows Phone 7 **nor move** a WhatsApp account to a Windows Phone 7.

It means that only creation or moving an account to WP7 will become impossible. Existing WhatsApp account will remain untouched, so keep using it... and don't reset your data :-)

Comment: I don't think so. Recently, I received a notification saying "the app will stop working" after Dec 31 on my phone.

Comment: @MarkYisri well, that would be inconsistent with the message they've put in their FAQ, that you linked to.

Comment: The app did not work after Dec 31, so I think this answer may be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of the type of app, you can't force an app written for WP8+ to run on Windows Phone 7 devices since those are using APIs that don't exist on these older devices.

Answer (score 1):

its already the 3rd of January and I am still using my Whatsapp messenger like normal on my lumia610.

*I also received the popup from Whatsapp saying it will stop working after 31/12/2016